# Remove double backslash from string with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, gsub

I have the following string:

```
string = "\"2014\\/jul\\/grandes\\/volvo-s-60-d5-momentum-1403253_2.jpg\""
```

that I want to gsub into this string:

```
string = "2014/jul/grandes/volvo-s-60-d5-momentum-1403253_2.jpg"
```

Here is how I thought it should work:

```
string.gsub(/\\./,'')
```

but this returns:

```
"\"2014julgrandesvolvo-s-60-d5-momentum-1403253_3.jpg\""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your string doesn't contain a double backslash, it looks like this: `"2014\/jul\/grandes\/volvo-s-60-d5-momentum-1403253_2.jpg"`. Note that the quotes are part of the string, i.e. the string starts with a `"` character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a “dot” in regexp for no reason. Instead of:

```
string.gsub(/\\./,'')
```

try:

```
string.gsub(/["\\]/,'')
```

Or, credits to @sawa, try this instead:

```
string.tr('"\\','')
```

Or, credits to @Chirantan:

```
string.delete('"\\')
```

Benchmarks: http://gist.github.com/dominikh/208915

Comment: string.gsub(/\\/,'') by using this it will return  "\"2014/jul/grandes/volvo-s-60-d5-momentum-1403253_2.jpg\"" which is not match with output

Comment: Huhh.. Regex I hate you.. ;)

Comment: For cases like this, it is more efficient to use `tr`.

Comment: @sawa How would that look?

Comment: @DeeptiKakade Its good.. That you learned it.. very good.. Me still throwing my hands.. hehehe.

Comment: @sawa "I hate you" is a indication to use `#tr`.. But you got it.. Great.

Comment: Just in case you're interested in performance benchmarks. https://gist.github.com/dominikh/208915 Single delete and tr win.

Comment: As Stefan commented, `delete` may be even better than `tr`. Where did that comment go?

Comment: @sawa Updated an answer.

Comment: @sawa I removed that comment because Chirantan already posted that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
string.delete('\\\"')
```

is one possible solution. But I'm sure there are better ones out there.

Comment: @Chirantan Oh, I was thoughtlessly examining the benchmarks. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Okay. You're crediting me for an answer I myself changed. I thought it should reflect. But anyway…

Answer (score 0):

Another *nasty one* using [`String#[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method. This is just for fun :-

```
string[/["\\]/] = '' until string[/["\\]/].nil?
# or
string[/["\\]/] = '' while string =~ /["\\]/
```

But `#gsub` is better way to solve this. If you don't want to modify the original *string*, then use [`String#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-slice) instead of `String#[]=`. That's it.